# Curl not working in Loop from list of URLs text file

Tags: bash, curl

I have a text file with about 50 URLs
Am trying to curl each of the URLs in the text file and grep to output a couple of lines from the GREP Match

I cannot understand why it wont work, as if i echo each line, it displays the URL correctly.
If i run the CURL manually with a URL and Grep it works. But once in the loop it simply does not output anything.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
echo "$line"
curl -s "$line" | grep "Telephone"
done <  links.txt
```

Sample Input:

```
https://qguild.co.uk/our-butchers/simpsons-butchers-south-hykeham/
https://qguild.co.uk/our-butchers/simpsons-butchers-spalding/
https://qguild.co.uk/our-butchers/simpsons-butchers-lincoln/
https://qguild.co.uk/our-butchers/simpsons-butchers-2/
```

Sample Output:

```
curl -s "https://qguild.co.uk/our-butchers/simpsons-butchers-south-hykeham/" | grep "Telephone"

<p>Simpsons Butchers,<br />Pennell`s Garden Centre,<br />Newark Road, South Hykeham, Lincoln, LN6 9NT. Telephone: 01522 695419<br />Monday - Saturday : 8am - 5.30pm Sunday : 10am - 4pm</p>

<p>Pennells Garden Centre, Newark Road, SOUTH HYKEHAM, LINCOLN LN6 9NT</p>                        
<p>Telephone: <a href="tel:01522-695419">01522 695419</a></p>                        <p>Email: <a href="mailto:sales@gsimpsonbutchers.co.uk">sales@gsimpsonbutchers.co.uk</a></p>                        
<p>Website: <a href="http://gsimpsonbutchers.co.uk/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">http://gsimpsonbutchers.co.uk/</a></p>
```

Comment: We need sample input and expected output.   
Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Provided sample input and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Using [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

If you want to keep the most of your code:

```
dos2unix links.txt
```

then

```
while IFS= read -r url; do
     xidel -e '//p[contains(., "Telephone")]/a/text()' -s "$url"
done < links.txt
```

or even shorter:

```
xargs < links.txt xidel -e '//p[contains(., "Telephone")]/a/text()' -s
```

##### Output

```
01522 695419
01775 723157
01522 525374
01529 460403
```

Comment: Nice clean solution, I was using Grep as i was also wanting the previous matched content, However using your example xidel and xargs i was able to output the information in a much cleaner format. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `links.txt` file is likely a DOS or Windows text file.

As such, it would have an extra carriage-return character at the end of each line, interfering with the end of the URL strings.

Convert your list of URLs to Unix text format with e.g. `dos2unix`, then try again.

Answer (score -2):

using input redirection and a `while` loop here is probably over-complicating things. Using `cat` and a `for` loop is simpler in this situation:

```
IFS=$(printf "\n")
for line in $(cat links.txt)
do
    echo "$line"
    curl -s "$line" | grep "Telephone"
done
```

Comment: Could you explain what using a `for` loop would solve here? A `for` loop is usually used for iterating over a static list (the shell expands the list in memory and iterates over it), while a `while` loop is used when the input is of indeterminate length, as when reading from a file, for example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).